# Prove that $f(z) = g(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

I need help with a problem.

> Let $f, g$ : $U$ → $\mathbb{C}$ analytic functions.
> If there's a squence {$z_n$} $⊂ U$ and $z_0 ∈ U$ such that:
> (1) $z_n ≠ z_0$ for all $n ∈ \mathbb{N}$
> (2) {$z_n$} → $z_0$
> (3) $f(z_n) = g(z_n)$ for all $n ∈ \mathbb{N}$
> Prove that $f(z) = g(z)$ for all $z ∈ U$.

I've thought of using a result that says that if there's a $z_0 ∈ U$, such that $f^{(n)}(z_0) = g^{(n)}(z_0)$ for all $n ∈ \mathbb{N}$, then $f(z) = g(z)$ for all $z ∈ U$.

For Taylor's theorem I have that:
$0 = f-g(z_n) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (f^{(n)}(z_0) - g^{(n)}(z_0))(1/n!)(z_n - z_0)^n$
And I would like to conclude that $f^{(n)}(z_0) - g^{(n)}(z_0) = 0$ for all $n ∈ \mathbb{N}$, because $(1/n!) ≠ 0$ and $(z_n - z_0) ≠ 0$ but I don't really sure if I can do that, because I would only be using that the equality is valid for some point and not for the entire sequence.
I would appreciate any comments or help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The zeros of $f-g$ have  a limit point. By the Identity Theorem for analytic functions $f=g$.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem